# maximum length form validation

Tags: validation, symfony

Just going through symblog.co.uk symfony2 tutorial. i'm kind of stuck in [validations](http://tutorial.symblog.co.uk/docs/validators-and-forms.html). At first it kept giving erros but i found [this](http://donna-oberes.blogspot.com/2013/09/symfony-2-symblog-tutorial-errors.html) article in which author corrects mistakes which source is tutorial being old. anyway, article tells me to change validator in

```
src/Blogger/BlogBundle/Entity/Enquiry.php:
```

from

```
$metadata->addPropertyConstraint('body', new MaxLength(50));
```

to:

```
$metadata->addPropertyConstraint('body', new Length(array('min'=> 50)));
```

It works, yay!
Same way i changed

```
 $metadata->addPropertyConstraint('subject', new MaxLength(50));
```

into

```
$metadata->addPropertyConstraint('subject', new Length(array('max'=>50)));
```

But this time there is no validation performed. Where is the mistake? How should maximum-length validation looks like?

Comment: **cleared your cache** ? :)

Answer (score 4):

According to the [docs](http://symfony.com/doc/current/reference/constraints/Length.html)

```
use Symfony\Component\Validator\Constraints as Assert; 

…

$metadata->addPropertyConstraint('firstName', new Assert\Length(array(
    'min'        => 2,
    'max'        => 10
)));
```